# How to do a validator for two controls dependent on each other

Tags: asp.net, validation

Hi I have a textbox and a datepicker control.

The validator requires that neither can be selected. ie. both blank. However if one has a value the other must also have a value.

Can anybody tell me how to implement this given that a CustomValidator requires a RequiredFieldValidator to fire?

Comment: Why not simply just implement all of that logic in the CustomValidator? It should be something like one line of code.

Comment: Also, note that it can only be validated at submission time, if you validate on control change, then it won't ever be possible to input values, because the other control will always prevent validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom validator and have the following client side code...

```
function CheckControls(sender, args){

    if(GetElement('Control1').Value != '')
    {
      if(GetElement('Control2').Value == '')
      {
         args.IsValid = false;
         return;
      }
    }

    args.IsValid = true;
    return;

}

function GetElement(id){

    if(document.all){
        return document.all[id];
    }else {
        return document.getElementById(id);        
    }

}
```

Comment: As far as I know though the CustomValidator will require a RequiredFieldValidator to function. Is this correct?

Comment: you're missing the failure state where control1 is not blank but control2 is. also don't bother with `document.all`, just use `document.getElementById`. @bigjim no you do not need a `RequiredFieldValidator` to use a `CustomValidator`.

Comment: The CustomValidator doesn't seem to fire the validate method without a RequiredFieldValidator though

Comment: @lincolnk - You're absolutely right - it needs Control1 and Control2 reversed in there. I thought some browsers don't support document.getElementId though?

Comment: @BigJim - You should just need the following control properties to fire (You need to provide one control to validate. <asp:CustomValidator id="ControlCustomValidator" 
        runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="Control1" 
        ValidateEmptyText="true" 
        ClientValidationFunction="CheckControls" 
        ErrorMessage="Your Error Message">*</asp:CustomValidator>
You can always hook up to the second control using ValidatorHookupControlID("<%= Control2.ClientID %>", 
     GetElement("<%= ControlCustomValidator.ClientID %>"));